# Python3 drop decimal places if not needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I see lots of answers about formatting floating numbers in Python 3 with a limited number of decimal places, e.g.:

```
>>> "{:.4f}".format(3.14159265359)
'3.1416'
```

But this formatting will keep redundant trailing 0's:

```
>>> "{:.4f}".format(3/4)
'0.7500'
```

What I'd like to have is to drop the trailing zeroes in a nice way:

```
>>> "{:.4f??}".format(3/4)
'0.75'
```

Using the `g` format seems to get closer to this, but it counts the digits BEFORE the decimal as part of the total field width, e.g.:

```
>>> "{:.4g}".format(3/4)
'0.75'
```

is perfect, but:

```
>>> "{:.4g}".format(3.14159265359)
'3.142'
```

instead of the desired `3.1416`

To clarify, whole numbers (e.g. `0` alone) shouldn't have a decimal at all.

Is this possible with `format` alone, or do I have to resort to dropping the trailing zeroes through string manipulation on the formatted number?

The documentation page I studied (besides searching the web): https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: So you want whole numbers?

Comment: @anarchy I want whole numbers to drop the decimal completely, but if a number has a fraction then show it up to 4 digits after the decimal (which is what `.4f` would give me) but without trailing zeroes (`.4f` would pad with zeroes if there aren't enough digits after the decimal).

Comment: look at my answer using ints will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a float to a string that has *at most* N digits after the decimal point, but does not include trailing 0's, you can use `round()` and then convert to a string.

```
>>> str(round(3.14159265359, 4))
'3.1416'
>>> str(round(3/4, 4))
'0.75'
>>> str(round(17, 4))
'17'
```

Comment: This will not work for 17.0

Comment: @ThePyGuy you are right :(

Looks like I'm back to `.rstrip` on the result of `round`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is possible with bare string formatting, but you could do:

```
>>> a = 3/ 4
>>> "{:.{a}f}".format(a, a=min(len(str(a).split('.')[-1]), 4))
'0.75'
>>> a = 3.14159265359
>>> "{:.{a}f}".format(a, a=min(len(str(a).split('.')[-1]), 4))
'3.1416'
>>>
```

Or why not `rstrip`:

```
>>> a = 3 / 4
>>> "{:.4f}".format(a).rstrip("0")
'0.75'
>>> a = 3.14159265359
>>> "{:.4f}".format(a).rstrip("0")
'3.1416'
>>>
```

**Numpy can do this better:**

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.format_float_positional(0.75, 4)
'0.75'
>>> np.format_float_positional(np.pi, 4)
'3.1416'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I found after posting is:

```
print('{:.4f}.format(a).rstrip('.0') or '0')
```

I still wonder if it's possible more elegantly.

Comment: `rstrip('.0')` would change "5500.00" to "55". I think instead you want `.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')`.

Comment: I added one numpy solution, which is the best I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round function` to do this work.
`round function` takes two `parameters`.
First one is the `floating number` that you want to round off and second one is the `number of places after decimal` you want.

```
a=10/3
print(round(a,4))
```

This will return `3.3333`.

```
a=3/4
print(round(a,4))
```

This will return `0.75`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `round`, and for that whole number condition, you can use `float.is_integer` :

```py
def func(x, digits):
    x = round(x, digits)
    return int(x) if float.is_integer(x) else x
```

**SAMPLE RUN**

```py
>>> func(3.14159265359, 4)
3.1416
>>> func(3.14000022, 4)
3.14
>>> func(3.000022, 4)
3
```

**PS:** You can convert the return values to string type, if needed.

Comment: Instead of `float.is_integer(x)` you could do `x.is_integer()` as well :)